# Move marker on google map with real time data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The database table is updated with new data in every 20 seconds. I wan't to move the marker on the map with new lat & lang. I tried to run a query every 30 seconds to get the last record of the table and update the position of the marker. Map loads, the marker is shown and the javascript function also called.  But the marker doesn't move. Please help..

```
<?php
include "db_connect.php";
$sql="SELECT * FROM temperature_details ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$firstrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


function getNewLatLang(){
$sql="SELECT * FROM temperature_details ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$latLang = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $latLang['latitude'].','. $latLang['longitude'];

}
?>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry"></script>

<div id="map" style="height:500px;width:100%;" ></div>

<script>

function initialize() {

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo $firstrow['latitude'].','. $firstrow['longitude'];?> ),
    myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), myOptions   ),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: myLatLng, map: map} );

marker.setMap( map );
moveMarker( map, marker );

}
function moveMarker( map,marker ) {


setInterval( function(){ 

    marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo getNewLatLang(); ?> ) );

    map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo getNewLatLang(); ?>));
    console.log("I am working");

}, 30000 );

};

initialize();

</script>
```

Comment: I removed the marker and set a new one in a similar situation.  Workaroundish but does the job.

Comment: @Max Please put the code..

Comment: Can't right now. on the road for a few more days limited to phone. sry

Comment: I tried. But it stills in the same place without moving.

Answer (score 0):

seems a var scoping problem  .... try declare the var  map and marker

```
<script>

// Declare the var for global scoping visibilty
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo $firstrow['latitude'].','. $firstrow['longitude'];?> ),
      myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatLng,
      ......
```

Answer (score 0):

change movemarker() to:

```
function moveMarker(){
  setInterval( function(){ 
      $.get("point", function(data){
      var latlng= $.parseJSON(data);
      mymarker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( {latlng} ) );
   });
}, 30000 );
```

And for "point" page do:

```
<?php
     //get last lat and long and send with under code
     echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```